# Run Keynote Presentation in a Window

Tags: display, keynote

Is there a way to run a Keynote presentation in a window instead of fullscreen?  I changed the resolution to one smaller than my display, and it displays it centered.  I need it in the upper left corner of the screen to record it with Camtasia.

Comment: Camstasia can record any portion of the screen, as far as I can remember.

Comment: It can, but unfortunately you can't specify the area of the screen when keynote is running. So I will probably make a wallpaper of just the 1024x768 in the middle of the screen so I can specify the area.  Although having it just grab the area would be idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can export it as a QuickTime movie and choose the Manual Advance Playback mode. It will behave exactly as a Presentation (click to advance and so on) and you will not loose any of the effects (animations, transitions, etc).

Once you have it in Quicktime then you can just present it in a window. Make sure you select Full Quality so you get the best possible movie out.

Comment: Thanks so much @Malife, I've used this feature quite a few times and it quite a few ways since you suggested it.  It rocks.  I just up-voted your answer and didn't accept it since it didn't technically answer the question.  I decided that since it is 99% of the way there and useful in so may other ways I would accept your answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: And then they killed the manual advance mode in Keynote 6. Not sure if they've fixed that in 7 or not.

Comment: Found this answer - https://discussions.apple.com/message/26418684#message26418684 which could work but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: The closest I have found in the newer versions is export to HTML, however some transition animations do not work quite the same.

Comment: As of April 2017, I think @ferventcoder is right, that exporting to HTML is the closest we can now get to the old QuickTime export with manual advance.  Another weakness to be aware of with the HTML export is that the text will appear a little blurry.  Not ideal for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The latest [update](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id409183694?mt=12) of keynote allow you to do play the presentation in a window.
Upgrade your keynote to 10.1 and simply play your slideshow via play-> play slideshow in screen.

> 10.1Jul 9, 2020 • Use the new “Play Slideshow in Window” option to have access to other applications while presenting locally or via
> video conferencing.