# How do I play a Keynote slideshow without going fullscreen?

Tags: macos, keynote

I am running Keynote 6.5.3 on OS X 10.10.5.  Is there a way to play a slideshow in Keynote in non-fullscreen mode?

Edit: I have edited my question slightly, since the suggestion to convert my Keynote files to Quicktime does not answer the question I had intended.

Edit2: I would prefer to not have to deal with the complexity of multiple file formats and apps for the simple task of reading through a large set of Keynote files, some of which I need on the screen at the same time due to diagrams etc.

Comment: You may want to see [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/3068/120171).  It is for the older version but this still works.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why converting the slideshow to Quicktime movie doesn't meet your needs. That would be enough for me to case a reopen vote - as written, this is a duplicate. Also list explicitly if you can connect a second monitor and describe the problem - what having a window allows you to do. Perhaps there are clever alternatives you might not be seeing.

Comment: I asked, what I believe was a simple question. "Can 'App X' be prevented from going fullscreen when I click on 'Y'?.  If there is no way to do this, please say so instead of claiming that my question is a duplicate of something that does not really answer my question.

Comment: Based on your "Edit 2" do you need to *play* the slide shows to read through the Keynote files?  You can open several at once in several windows.  Playing and opening are two different things.  Please elaborate.  Having trouble following your logic.  That is my fault, I want to help if I can.

Comment: @bjbk quite a few of these Keynote files have animations. It would be really convenient to just hit a key to advance through.