# Fullscreen App(s) In Splitscreen

Tags: keynote

How can I use a fullscreen app (specifically a Keynote presentation) while displaying another app (specifically a movie) simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't.

[Apple's splitscreen](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948) simply doesn't currently support that. Unless the app specifically supports it's fullscreen mode in splitscreen, only the windowed mode will work (if it's supported there.)

With that said, you can [export a Keynote presentation to another format like QuickTime which supports splitscreen playback.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/run-keynote-presentation-in-a-window) You can then run this in a window with a splitscreen, and the relevant other app (such as the movie) on the other side.